# Rotate a cube around it's diagonal

Tags: css, animation, math, geometry

I have this cube that I rotate it so I would look trough it's diagonal. How could I rotate this cube around this particular diagonal? I tried different rotations but nothing seems to fit me.
I am looking for CSS only solution/explenation.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  perspective: 10000px;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 50vh;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.cube figure {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cube .front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube .back {
  transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube .right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube .left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube .top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube .bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.cube {
  transform: rotateY(35deg) rotateX(45deg);
}
.cube:hover {
  transition: all 1s;
  transform: rotateY(35deg) rotateX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="cube">
    <figure class="front"></figure>
    <figure class="back"></figure>
    <figure class="right"></figure>
    <figure class="left"></figure>
    <figure class="top"></figure>
    <figure class="bottom"></figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it - this solved my problem (hover over cube).

Explanation: the transform stack is evaluated from right to left. So, if we want to rotate an element that is transformed around the z axis, we need to set this transform the first one.

If the original is

```
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

then

```
transform: rotateZ(value) translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

will rotate the element around the viewer z axis (the desired effect)

```
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateZ(value);
```

would rotate the element around its Z axis

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  perspective: 10000px;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 50vh;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cube figure {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cube .front  { transform: rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 100px ); }
.cube .back   { transform: rotateX( 180deg ) translateZ( 100px ); }
.cube .right  { transform: rotateY(  90deg ) translateZ( 100px ); }
.cube .left   { transform: rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 100px ); }
.cube .top    { transform: rotateX(  90deg ) translateZ( 100px ); }
.cube .bottom { transform: rotateX( -90deg ) translateZ( 100px ); }

.cube {
  transform: rotateY(35deg) rotateX(45deg);
}

.cube:hover {
  transition: all 1s;
  transform:rotateZ(60deg) rotateY(35deg) rotateX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="cube">
    <figure class="front"></figure>
    <figure class="back"></figure>
    <figure class="right"></figure>
    <figure class="left"></figure>
    <figure class="top"></figure>
    <figure class="bottom"></figure>
  </div>
</section>
```